# showModalDialog third argument error

Tags: javascript

I have url like this:

```
 window.showModalDialog(
   "../../something/something.aspx?ConfigID=6&QQfwQrfJpy=<%=LeaseID%>&jFnCppJunX=" 
         + activ_id.value 
         + "&jwsKqmhrBK=" 
         + rama.value,
         null, "dialogWidth:700px;dialogHeight:460px");
```

but I think the url is wrong   constructed because activ_id.value is no set reference to object . I am 100% sure I need this paratameter but i think my url is wrong constructed.

My URL working perfect without last paramater like this :

```
 window.showModalDialog(
       "../../something/something.aspx?ConfigID=6&QQfwQrfJpy=<%=LeaseID%>&jFnCppJunX=" 
             + activ_id.value 

             null, "dialogWidth:700px;dialogHeight:460px");
```

but i should insert one more paramater and it stop worked

Comment: Looks ok, but perhaps you need to use `document.getElementById("activ_id").value` or `document.getElementsByName("activ_id")[0].value`

Comment: Your post is not at all clear.. please explain your issue clearly.

Comment: So, you aren't getting response from server when you add the last parameter?

Comment: Object reference  set no istance to an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog#Compatibility),

> The third argument (for additional options) is not present in the HTML5 version, and is (safely) ignored by both Safari and Chrome.

means the other browser like IE can't ignore the third argument. Hence, it will show some error.

I have also found this [thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-comments/2009Apr/0001.html) and the [reply](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-comments/2009Jun/0000.html).

I am not sure how to solve this, maybe running in older html version (i.e HTML4) might solve the problem.

For more information, refer this [**MSDN link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the last quote in your string.

```
rama.value"
```

should probably be

```
rama.value
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this:

```
"../../something/something.aspx?
```

to this:

```
"/something/something.aspx?
```

or maybe to this:

```
"http://example.com/something/something.aspx?
```

Comment: Another sad soul who doesn't know about the conveniences of `..` directories...it refers to the parent directory